# Transfer tokens from Smart Contract to address using signTransaction + private key

Tags: web3js, contract-development, parity

I tried several links like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611117/how-to-authenticate-and-send-contract-method-using-web3-js-1-0), but when I call transfer function from contract and try to send tokens, its sending 'ethers' not 'tokens', 
how can I send tokens by signing a transaction offline using private key and later uploading it to network?

Any help would be appreciated a lot!

Thanks,
Surinder